# Frequentist properties of p-values in relation to type I error

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, p-value, type-i-and-ii-errors

This question is related to frequentist properties of p-values and their relation to type I error and why the results from an online simulation differ from what I would have expected.

Assume that I perform an experiment and do hypothesis testing at a significance level of 0.05. Next, I compute the p-value. If it is less than 0.05 then I reject the null hypothesis, if it is greater than 0.05, then I accept the null hypothesis (as per Neyman-Pearson hypothesis testing). Now, if I repeated this experiment hundreds of times (each time either accepting or rejecting the null hypothesis at 0.05), then the type I error (chance of rejecting a true null hypothesis) should be around 5% is that not correct?

I wanted to test my understanding so I used this java applet: http://www.stat.duke.edu/~berger/applet2/pvalue.html to simulate exactly such an experiment. I kept everything at their default levels in the applet except in the top bar where I changed the range of p-values from 0 to 0.05. Essentially, this is allowing me to 'reject' all those experiments where the p-value was < 0.05 and find out how many H0 were incorrectly rejected (H0 was actually true) and how many H0 were correctly rejected (H1 was actually true).

I would have assumed that I would get around 5% true nulls; however, when I ran it, I get around 12% H0, and 88% H1, which means that 12% of the numbers I rejected were true nulls, while 88% were false, this is a type 1 error of 12%. What am I missing? Can someone please explain why the applet came up with these results?

Comment: I was not able to run your applet. However, came across [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ax0tDcFkPic) which gives a good understanding of p-value.

Comment: Did you run it both for $H_0$ true and for $H_1$ true before computing the rejection rate? You should get a $5~\%$ rejection rate if you _only_ run it under $H_0$. That's what is meant by type I error rate. The probability of rejection is larger under $H_1$, so if you run it under both hypotheses the rejection rate should be above $5~\%$ (depending on how many times you run it under each hypothesis).

Comment: I agree with MansT.  It sounds like you have a misunderstanding above the type I error and the p-value. You should be testing under the null hypothesis.  Under the null hypothesis the p-value is uniform on [0, 1] and consequently will be below 0.05 5% of the time.  Under an alternative hypothesis the distribution of the p-value will not be uniform and will tend to be higher than 0.05.

Comment: @MånsT, hmm, how would I run it under only the null hypothesis? The applet does not give me an option to do that as far as I can tell :S

Comment: @MichaelChernick I'm not quite sure I follow, doesn't the p-value depend solely on the distribution assuming the null hypothesis is true? The non-central alternative distribution only comes into play for power and sample size as far as I know

Comment: @BYS2 Yes the p-value is the probability of getting as extreme or more extreme of a value when the null hypothesis is true. So it is meaningless to talk about the p-value under an alternative hypothesis.  I guess what I meant was that if you are simulating with a non-null distribution but you pretend that the null hypothesis is true and calculate the probability of observing the observed test statistic or a more extreme value, that probability would not have a uniform distribution and would tend to be higher than 0.05.  I think of it like a p-value because it is computed like a p-value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can't for the life of me get that applet to run in my browser, so I'll try to give an example using [R](http://www.r-project.org) instead.

As noted in the comments, it seems that what caused the confusion is that the applet runs under both the alternative and the null hypothesis. To check that the type I error rate really is $0.05$ you need to run it under the null hypothesis *only*.

Here is an example where we use the $t$-test to test whether the mean $\mu$ of a normal distribution equals $0$. That is, we test $H_0: \mu=0.$ We simulate $10,000$ samples from ${\rm N}(0,\sigma^2)$ and compute the $p$-value for each sample.

We also simulate $10,000$ samples from the ${\rm N}(0.25,\sigma^2)$ and ${\rm N}(0.5,\sigma^2)$ distributions and compute the $p$-values.

```
set.seed(201208)
B<-10000
p.values1<-p.values2<-p.values3<-vector(length=B)

for(i in 1:B)
{
    x1<-rnorm(25)
    p.values1[i]<-t.test(x1)$p.value

    x2<-rnorm(25,0.25)
    p.values2[i]<-t.test(x2)$p.value

    x3<-rnorm(25,0.5)
    p.values3[i]<-t.test(x3)$p.value
}
```

We can now compute the proportion of samples that lead to a rejection of $H_0: \mu=0$ at the $5~\%$ level:

```
sum(p.values1<=0.05)/B
sum(p.values2<=0.05)/B
sum(p.values3<=0.05)/B
```

In this case, the answers are $0.505$ under the null hypothesis ($\approx 0.05$, just as we would expect!), $0.2187$ when $\mu=0.25$ and $0.6754$ when $\mu=0.5$.

We can visualize the results by plotting histograms of the $p$-values:
[image: Histograms]

For $\mu=0$, the $p$-values are uniformly distributed on $\lbrack 0,1\rbrack$. Under the alternatives, the distribution of the $p$-values has more mass closer to $0$ (more so the further away from $0$ that $\mu$ is).

We can also compare the distribution of the $p$-values using box-and-whiskers-plots:
[image: Boxplots]

Hopefully it is clear from the picture that the probability of rejection, i.e. the probability that the $p$-value is lower than $0.05$ depends on whether the null hypothesis or an alternative hypothesis is true. In this case, you should only expect the rejection rate to be $0.05$ when $\mu=0$.

The code for producing these plots is:

```
#Boxplots:
boxplot(p.values1,p.values2,p.values3,names=c("mu=0","mu=0.25","mu=0.5"))

# Histograms:
par(mfrow=c(1,3))
hist(p.values1,main="mu=0")
hist(p.values2,main="mu=0.25")
hist(p.values3,main="mu=0.5")
```

Comment: Brilliant, that was a great explanation! One question though, you say "In this case, the answers are 0.505 under the null hypothesis (≈0.05, just as we would expect!), 0.2187 when μ=0.25..." Don't you mean 0.0505 (and not 0.505) under the null hypothesis? and not sure why you can't access the applet :(, the main page is http://www.stat.duke.edu/~berger/p-values.html though in case you want to check it out

Comment: @BYS2: You're quite right, it should of course be 0.0505!