# Should there be bands in this chart of random p-values?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, p-value

I generated p-values from 10K trials with null hypothesis set to true. My goal was to see what the distribution of random p-values is like. The sample size of each test was 2000 with a 5% success rate. p-values calculated using "N-1 two proportion test" based on normal distribution (Sauro 2012). Here's the formula:

[image: N-1 test]

Are there ranges of p-values that are unlikely, as this chart shows? Or is there some flaw in my method?

I do remember reading something about p-values below 0.05 being more likely than around 0.05, but I don't see that here. Instead I see this banding closer to the high p-values.

[image: Random p-values]

I also plotted the density of p-values. This has minor waviness at the high end of the chart, which I guess corresponds to the big bands. The density chart usually shows a slight peak at 0.1.

[image: Density plot of random p-values]

Can anyone confirm any of this and/or point me to some info on expected distribution of p-values?

Comment: What is a "null test" and how exactly did you compute the p-values?

Comment: More details of what you did are needed. Were these chi-square tests by any chance?

Comment: By "null test" I meant "experiment where null hypothesis is true". I calculated p-values using the "two proportion test" which is mathematically equivalent to chi^2 but uses normal distribution.

Comment: I edited the first paragraph with link to formula used.

Comment: Your link gives "You have reached your viewing limit for this book"... which is no help at all. Please edit to give the essential information in your question (at the least, copy your comment up).

Comment: [This post](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/153249/distribution-of-p-values-binomial-test/153267#153267) discusses where the bands originate. If you need something not covered there, you may want to refine your question.