# Long-run behavior of p-values? (simulation)

Tags: hypothesis-testing, sampling, p-value, simulation, expected-value

I was wondering why the expected value (i.e., long-run average) of the p-values from a simulation of a binomial experiment in the below experiment becomes roughly about $.61$, *regardless* of $p$; the probability of success?

Here is my simulation code in R:

```
simulation <- function(n, p, n.sim){
    fun = function(){
      x = rbinom(1, n, p)
     pe = x/n
p.value = binom.test(x, n, p)[[3]]
    c(p.value, pe)
}
sim <- t(replicate(n.sim, fun()))
par(mfcol = c(2, 2))
plot(sim[, 1], 1:n.sim, xlim = c(0, 1), pch = 19, col = 2, main = "p.value")
plot(sim[, 2], 1:n.sim, xlim = c(0, 1), pch = 19, col = 4, main = "proportion")
abline(v = p, lty = 2, col = 2)
hist(sim[, 1], main = "p.value")
hist(sim[, 2], main = "proportion")
list(p.value = mean(sim[, 1]), proportion = mean(sim[, 2]))
}
simulation(n = 15, p = .1, n.sim = 1e3) ## Change p to whatever and p.value remains around .61
```

[image]

Comment: Since p-values are uniformly distributed under the null (at least approximately, depending on the circumstances and the test), and uniform variables have a mean of $0.5$, it sounds like your computer experiments are in line with theory.

Comment: @whuber, but change the sample size (I should say `n` to 15) and then what happens?

Comment: It will make no material difference.  Hypothesis tests are *constructed* so that p-values will have uniform distributions under the null hypothesis, or as close to uniform as is feasible, regardless of sample size and regardless of the alternative.  (A "composite" null creates a complication that I am glossing over here, because it's not a conceptual one.)

Comment: @whuber, why uniform under the null? Is this difficult to explain?

Comment: Not at all: it has been [explained many times on this site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=hypothesis%20uniform%20null).

Comment: The case of a simple null but discrete test statistic is also discussed [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/153249/non-uniform-distribution-of-p-values-when-simulating-binomial-tests-under-the-nu/)

Comment: I think @Glen_b's suggestion is a far closer match for a duplicate here because the distribution is not exactly uniform in this case - but even that does not quite cover the question originally raised, which is what the mean p-value is, for a given $n$. (It does address the fact that the p-value tends to 0.5 as you increase the binomial $n$, but that was not the question here.)

Comment: @Silverfish, thank you for understanding my question.

Comment: If you aren't satisfied that the suggested duplicate answers what you were asking, you might try editing the question to clarify what you understand already (from the suggested duplicate or elsewhere) and what else it is that you want to know.